# Is it possible use jersey with jax-ws in the same project

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rs

Is it possible use jersey(jax-rs) and jax-ws in the same project?
I using Jboss.

Comment: What do you mean "possible" here? You can mix and match the features as long as you know when to use which.

Comment: I'm trying to use the jersey and jax-ws, but are experiencing a conflict between them. When I call the webservice in other project using  jax-ws alone works, but when I put the jersey and the jax-ws does not work.

Comment: What's the conflict? It depends on the configuration you've made too. Come up with a detailed question mentioning how your configuration of these two features looks like and the error details. "Doesn't work" is too generic to infer anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Both JAX-RS and JAX-WS are Java EE standards supported by JBoss (since 5.X.GA or 4.X.EAP). So technically it is not a problem.

If you ask "does it makes sens", the answer is - it depends. If you want to expose lightweight API for your application, then REST web services with JAX-RS make perfect sense.

If you do some integration with third party system and you need special features like reliable messaging, advanced security settings, you need (or want) to have precise description of web service API (in terms of WSDL and XSD), than usually JAX-WS SOAP/WSDL web services are better (but not always).

If, in you application you are doing both things, just use both technologies.

Comment: Sure. My application is exhibiting its services via rest with the jersey. What happens is that I'm trying to make a call to a webservice in Jax-ws within my application and not working. When I call this webservice with Jax-ws in a standalone application I have no problem, only when I put in my application that uses the jersey. –